# Cut every 100th column from csv

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have a data file of numbers seperated by tabs, like this

```
1 2 3 4
2 4 6 8
```

My real file is 50000 columns wide and I only need every 100th column (column 100, 200, 300, 400, ...).
Now I would like to remove all the other columns.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `awk` is for:

```
awk '{for(i=100;i<=NF;i+=100){printf "%s ",$i;} print ""}' file > output
```

Or, if you can have spaces inside your fields, specify tab as the field separator:

```
awk -F'\t' '{for(i=100;i<=NF;i+=100){printf "%s ",$i;} print ""}' file > output
```

Alternatively, you could use Perl:

```
perl -ane 'for($i=99;$i<=$#F;$i+=100){print "$F[$i] "}' file > output
```

To do this for multiple files, you can use a shell loop (assuming you want to run this on all files in the current directory):

```
for f in *; do
  awk '{for(i=100;i<=NF;i+=100){printf "%s ",$i;} print ""}' "$f" > "$f".new;
done
```

Comment: I tried the first solution and it worked. Is there a way to automate this if I want to cut the columns from multiple files, which are called xy_1.txt, xy_2.txt, xy_3.txt, ...?

Comment: @BlubBla see update.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know if it's appropriated with big files, you can do this with `cut`:

```
cut -d " " -f -100 < [your file]
```

Comment: This will only print field 100, not every 100th field as the OP requested.

Comment: No it won't, unless you forget the dash before 100.

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad. This will print fields 1 to 100 though. Still not what the OP wants.

Comment: With `cut` you could use `cut -d' ' -f$(seq -s, 0 100 N)` where `N` is the total number of columns but as you said, this won't work with big numbers (you'll most likely get an _argument list too long_).

Comment: I just realize what "every 100th column" means. Indeed, the awk method is the one, especially with the NR operator. Cheers!